# Add helper text in custom-header section in admin

Tags: customization, admin-menu, custom-header

In my custom theme I created a custom header section :

```
 add_theme_support( 'custom-header', array(
    'video' => true,
    'flex-width' => true,
    'flex-height' => true,
    'width' => 1920,
    'height' => 677,
   ) );
```

but I want to add some additional info in the admin area where you chose the images to upload, and if possible to change the default text that now is: "Click “Add new image” to upload an image... etc"

Thank you.

Comment: Please share which theme you are using? If you go through code you can check the customizer php file in which you can see the control added. But that is depends on theme. You can search in your theme and you can edit the text.

Comment: I am not using any theme, I am building my own theme